# How to upload Data to to firebase storage then download onto another view controller

Tags: swift, firebase, download, upload, firebase-storage

Hi I'm fairly new to Firebase and I've been trying to improve my coding skills, I have set up a Firebase storage and linked it to my application. I have managed to so far upload images to the storage database which i can see in my firebase console. My aim is to once uploaded the image i click on a button which then segues to another view controller and then automatically downloads the image to display to the user.

Now In the console i keep getting the 'success' message but the image does not display. I have tried to also overcome this by trying a protocol/delegate method whereby i override the segue func and create a delegate within my original VC as a reference to the endGame view controller where the image should display. I am still unable to download and display the image. Can anyone tell me how i can download not only an image but any type of data to another view controller? Also side note does anyone know how i can upload string information to the the storage and download that also?

Any help would be appreciated, cheers!

Uploading Data Code :-

```
    let refToStorage = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "personalPhoto/profilePhoto.jpg")
        guard let imageData = self.profileImageView.image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.75) else { return }
        let uploadMetadata = StorageMetadata.init()
        uploadMetadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"

        refToStorage.putData(imageData, metadata: uploadMetadata) { (StorageMetadata, Error) in
            if Error != nil {
                print(Error!)
                print("No still didnt work")
            }   else {
                print("Image was uploaded, I got this \(String(describing: StorageMetadata))")
            }
        }
```

Downloading Data Code :-

```
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "personalPhoto/profilePhoto.jpg")

    storageRef.getData(maxSize: 4 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, Error) in
        if Error != nil {
            print("Error, \(Error?.localizedDescription)")
        }   else {
            print("Yes")
            self.downloadPersonalImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Grats on your progress! A couple of questions; are you uploading the file, switching to another viewController and attempting to download the file all during the same process? If so, why? If the file was just uploaded you wouldn't need to download it as you would already have the file in memory for the other viewController. Also, when a file is uploaded, you'll want to store its URL in the Database so you can use that to access the file in the future. Take a look at Upload guide and note the code section where you can get the url *// You can also access to download URL after upload.*

Comment: Oh, careful with var names as well. This (StorageMetadata, Error) should be this (metaData, error). Capital letters are used for Class and Structure names whereas vars should be lowercased and not the exact same name as a class name. That avoids confusion. The downloading code looks correct - I copy and pasted it into my app and it works. Your question says is prints 'success' but the code should print "Yes" if it was successful. Is it printing "Yes"? If so, take a look at `self.downloadPersonalImage.image` as perhaps that's not valid or maybe hidden in the UI

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Jay! I managed to download the information from the storage onto my new view controller upon switching to it!